# How to store ps command output in csv format?

Tags: linux, shell

I am making a process monitoring application. Now my need is

1. To get process related data (pid, process name, cpu usage, memory usage and virtual memory usage) for all the running processes.
2. After completing the first step I want to store the retrieved data into *csv* format.

My code part is:

```
ps -e -o pid,lstart,%cpu,%mem,cmd >> output.csv
```

But it is storing all values in only one cell. Meaning it is not being separated by a comma.

***output.csv* example:**

```
  PID                  STARTED %CPU %MEM CMD
    1 Mon Feb 25 00:00:01 2019  0.0  0.1 examplecommand1
    2 Mon Feb 25 00:00:01 2019  0.0  0.0 examplecommand2
                          (...)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Running your command on Fedora 29 and Ubuntu 18 results in *`error: improper list`*. Pleas show the actual commands you are running, and the actual output of the file.

Comment: Jww- I think you have added space after comma that's why you are getting wrong result. I agaun cheked same command on Ubuntu18 it is giving proper result.

Comment: @monoj - I copied and pasted the exact command you provided.

Comment: Sir, please have a look just now I ran.                                                               
  ps -e -o pid,lstart,%cpu,%mem,cmd
  PID                  STARTED %CPU %MEM CMD
    1 Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018  0.0  0.0 /sbin/init
    2 Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018  0.0  0.0 [kthreadd]
    3 Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018  0.0  0.0 [migration/0]
    4 Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018  0.0  0.0 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018  0.0  0.0 [stopper/0]
    6 Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018  0.0  0.0 [watchdog/0]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like the following code I wrote:

`ps -e -o %p, -o lstart -o ,%C, -o %mem -o ,%c > output.csv`

**Brief explanation:**

The `-o` option can be used multiple times in a `ps` command to specify the format.
In order to control which separator is used we can use *AIX format descriptors*. We can specify our needed separators like, e.g. `%p,`. Since *AIX format descriptors* are not available for every piece of data, but only for some of the data (for example in our case there are no *AIX format descriptors* for `%mem` and for `lstart`), we plant `%mem` and `lstart` around the available *AIX format descriptors* to achieve the comma separation. For example [this site](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) provides information about the `ps` command for further readings.

***output.csv* example:**

```
  PID,                 STARTED,%CPU,%MEM,COMMAND
    1,Mon Feb 25 00:00:01 2019, 0.0, 0.1,examplecommand1
    2,Mon Feb 25 00:00:01 2019, 0.0, 0.0,examplecommand2
                           (...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is working as I expected. But could you pls explain how does it give cpu% result while you don't write 'cpu%' in your given command.

Comment: %C is CPU% column

Comment: @eckes Thanks for clearing my doubt. one more need. Can we get swap/virtual memory used by each process in the same list in a column?

Comment: The man page lists the formt specifies like vsz. I don’t think ps gives swap usage per process. https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/procps/ps.1.en.html

Comment: @eckes I was aware of it "I don’t think ps gives swap usage per process.". That's why I asked to you. Is there any other way to get it but it should be in the same above list.

Comment: Most tools don’t show it since it is hard to calculate and then very missleading. I think there is a `VmSwap` line in /proc/<pid>/status

Answer (score 1):

```
csv-ps -c pid,cmd,%cpu,vm_rss_KiB,vm_size_KiB
```

csv-ps is from https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools.

Comment: Can you pls explain a bit more your solution?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. What do you want to know?

Comment: I was meaning you to explain your answer, to be cliser to guidelins https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please explain to me what is not clear in my answer. I read your link and I don't see which of the guide lines my answer doesn't follow.

Comment: simply you should add some explanation of the command you posted instead of just putting the link, to follow stackoverflow guidelines. The other answer of the question is a nice example of this

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command below.

You'll probably get the results you want.

`-o %% -o` 
Due to the corresponding options between each column
`%` is inserted,
It is replaced by `,` again.

Now, the columns are intuitively separated by `,`, but since there are still invalid spaces, the spaces are further removed with `tr -d ' '`.

However, `%mem` and `pcpu` in the header line are
This can be confusing because `%MEM`, `%CPU` are separated by another "space", creating two empty columns in the header line.

So if we move the column names one space after the two empty columns in the header line, we get:
You can get the results you want.

```
 ps -e -o group, -o %% -o gid, -o %% -o user,  -o %% -o uid, -o %% -o pid, -o %% -o ppid, -o %% -o %mem, -o %% -o rss, -o %% -o vsz, -o %% -o time, -o %% -o stime, -o %% -o etime, -o %% -o nice, -o %% -o pcpu, -o %% -o pmem, -o %% -o lstart, -o %% -o priority, -o %% -o start, -o %% -o userns, -o %% -o vsize, -o %% -o vsz, -o %% -o wchan, -o %% -o command | grep -v grep | sed 's/%/,/g' | tr -d ' '>>output.csv
```